# Can you format input text at the BASH prompt?

Tags: bash

I have a custom BASH prompt I’m (finally) happy with. One final thing I would like is for the command the user types to be in bold text, but not the prompt or the output of the command. Is there a way to do this?

Obviously I could finish the prompt with the escape code for bold text, but is there any way to clear it when the user presses Enter?

Comment: This is interesting question I don't believe there is a way to do this directly in bash but which terminal emulator are you using?  I will do a little digging and see what I come up with.

Comment: Just quickly looking it appears this is can be done with gnome terminal I don't use gnome so can't confirm but there is setting for command/prompt and then a setting for the output.  But no matter what emulator you are using I think that is the way to address this meaning via your emulator not bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could finish the prompt with the escape code for bold text

Do it.

> but is there any way to clear it when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Yes, in Bash with the following `DEBUG` trap:

```
trap 'printf "\033[0m" >&2' DEBUG
```

> ```
> trap [-lp] [arg] [sigspec …]
> ```
>
> […] If a `sigspec` is `DEBUG`, the command `arg` is executed before every simple command, […]

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap))</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Never would have come up with this, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Actually found an issue with this now in that I end up with mangled text at certain points, characters left over from previous inputs etc. when moving through history. Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: @tsvallender Are you sure the issue is because of the trap? [Check your `PS1`](https://superuser.com/a/367280/432690) first.

Comment: Thanks, yes I didn't mean to infer it was the trap causing it, just that I didn't have a complete solution. But that was the issue anyway. Thanks very much!